# I'm getting error like Invalid id value for this SObject type in after update call using apex trigger

Tags: apex, after-trigger

My Trigger Scenario:

write an apex trigger to update the related contacts with the latest country field value
whenever it changes on the parent account record.

My Implementation:

```apex
public static void updateCountry(List<Account> lstAcc,Map<Id,Account> mapoldAcc)
    {
       Set<Id> accIds=new Set<Id>();
       Map<Id,String> mapCountry=new Map<Id,String>();
       List<Contact> conToUpdate=new List<Contact>();
       for(Account acc:lstAcc)
       {
          if(mapoldAcc!=null)
          {
             if(mapoldAcc.get(acc.Id).Country__c !=acc.Country__c)
             {
                  accIds.add(acc.Id);
             }
          }
          else
          {
              accIds.add(acc.Id);
          }
       }
       if(!accIds.isEmpty())
       {

          // First Approach //   
          for(Account ac:lstAcc)
          {
              mapCountry.put(ac.Id,ac.Country__c);
          }
           for(Id accId:mapCountry.keySet())
           {
               conToUpdate.add(new Contact(Id=accId,Country__c=mapCountry.get(accId)));    
           }
           
          // 2nd Approach //
          //List<Contact> conList=[Select AccountId,Name,Country__c from Contact where AccountId in:accIds];
          /*
          for(Contact c:conList)
          {
              if(mapCountry.containsKey(c.AccountId))
              {
                  String country=mapCountry.get(c.AccountId);
                  if(country!=null)
                  {
                      c.Country__c=country;
                      conToUpdate.add(c);
                  }
              }
          }
          */
       }

       if(!conToUpdate.isEmpty())
       {
          update conToUpdate;
       }
    }
```

If I use the first approach, I'm getting an error like 'Invalid ID value for this SObject type.' However, if I use the second approach, then my code is completely working fine. Why is this 'Invalid ID value for this SObject type' error occurring? I would greatly appreciate an explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first approach, you are trying to create a new Contact using AccountId. Change the line to

```
conToUpdate.add(new Contact(AccountId = accId, Country__c=mapCountry.get(accId)));
```

and it will work.

The Id field in Contact is automatically assigned upon Contact creation,  so you cannot insert that value. You can however, insert the AccountId value, which creates a lookup relationship.

Comment: Your example is incomplete.  `update` always requires a value in the `Id` field, so your line must include an assignment for the `Id` field.

Answer (score 0):

You need to retrieve the contacts in order to get their IDs, and then you can update the country on the contacts.  Approach 1 fails because you are using the Account ID in the contact ID field, which is wrong.